# why some asset files are too many redirects in https?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
#Options -Indexes

# enable apache rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

I have used this htaccess in root directory. after that all requests are handle index.php. here, some js/jpg files are redirects too many times with https url (https://example.com or https://www.example.com). but in http it works fine.

why this was happen? anybody help to solve this problem.

modernizer.js file redirects like this, (test it from gtmatrix tool result and also developer tools)

```
 https://www.example.com/assets/js/modernizer.js
 https://example.com/assets/js/modernizer.js
 https://example.com/assets/js/modernizer.js
```

[image]

actually i cannot understand what happens. hostgator linux hosting is used for this. it works fine in http (not https).
suppose if i open in new tab this file then https://www.example.com/assets/js/modernizer.js url is redirect to https://example.com/assets/js/modernizer.js

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I try One solution to solve this issue (this is not exact solution i try only to solve cached file redirects), actually problem occurs due to browser cache memory not in above htaccess. (Preciously I had try in both incognito and cache cleared browser but it still these redirects happens in some files) so i try to change name of these files in above screen shoot then reload it after that this problem is solved.

my guess is this problem is happens due to cache. because previously we used leverage browser caching in htaccess after that this was removed due to solve the problem.

above htaccess is worked fine now.